# How to serialize Java8 LocalDateTime to json as calendar object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jsr310

Im using jackson-datatype-jsr310 module, which supports LocalDateTime serialization.
but by default, it serializes date/time as "[2022,6,29,17,15,54]".

But I need to override this behaviour to serialize/deserialize it in "Calendar" format, ex. as json object

```
"arrivalDate": {
  "month": "JUNE",
  "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
  "dayOfYear": 180,
  "nano": 0,
  "year": 2022,
  "monthValue": 6,
  "dayOfMonth": 29,
  "hour": 12,
  "minute": 53,
  "second": 46,
  "chronology": {
    "id": "ISO",
    "calendarType": "iso8601"
  }
}
```

The setting should be not global for all application, but only for specific ObjectMapper instantiation for internal purposes.

Comment: interesting, that it was working with Spring boot 2.2.6, but after upgrade to Sping Boot 2.5.5 default date serialization format changed and functionality is broken

Comment: What's stopping you from creating your own serializer/deserializer?

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Let's consider Jackson 2.13.3 as the current version.

## Analysis

### Such feature seems to be absent out of the box

Please, see the following piece of source code and note the comment there: [jackson-databind/BeanSerializerFactory.java at jackson-databind-2.13.3 · FasterXML/jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/jackson-databind-2.13.3/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerFactory.java#L883-L889):

```
    protected JsonSerializer<?> _findUnsupportedTypeSerializer(SerializerProvider ctxt,
            JavaType type, BeanDescription beanDesc)
        throws JsonMappingException
    {
        // 05-May-2020, tatu: Should we check for possible Shape override to "POJO"?
        //   (to let users force 'serialize-as-POJO'?
        final String errorMsg = BeanUtil.checkUnsupportedType(type);
```

Maybe, it is worth opening the appropriate GitHub issue.

## Possible workaround solution

Introduce and use a custom `BeanSerializerFactory` implementation that will not prevent using the default Jackson bean serializers for the JSR 310 types (the `java.time` package) and Joda types (the `org.joda.time` package).

To understand the idea, please, refer to the implementation of the methods:

- `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._findUnsupportedTypeSerializer()`.
- `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.BeanUtil.checkUnsupportedType()`.
- `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.BeanUtil.isJava8TimeClass()`.

### `CustomBeanSerializerFactory` class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.SerializerFactoryConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory;

public final class CustomBeanSerializerFactory extends BeanSerializerFactory {
    protected CustomBeanSerializerFactory(final SerializerFactoryConfig config) {
        super(config);
    }

    @Override
    protected JsonSerializer<?> _findUnsupportedTypeSerializer(
        final SerializerProvider ctxt,
        final JavaType type,
        final BeanDescription beanDesc
    ) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

### `Schedule` class

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public final class Schedule {
    private final LocalDateTime arrivalDate;

    public Schedule(final LocalDateTime arrivalDate) {
        this.arrivalDate = arrivalDate;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getArrivalDate() {
        return arrivalDate;
    }
}
```

### `Program` class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public final class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(
            2022, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        );
        final Schedule schedule = new Schedule(localDateTime);

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializerFactory(
            new CustomBeanSerializerFactory(null)
        );
        final String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(schedule);
        System.out.println(jsonString);
    }
}
```

The program output:

```
{"arrivalDate":{"nano":6,"year":2022,"monthValue":1,"dayOfMonth":2,"hour":3,"minute":4,"second":5,"month":"JANUARY","dayOfWeek":"SUNDAY","dayOfYear":2,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}}
```

## Additional references

- GitHub issue: [Spring Boot 2.5.0 and InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default · Issue #26859 · spring-projects/spring-boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26859).

  - Comment: [Spring Boot 2.5.0 and InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default · Issue #26859 · spring-projects/spring-boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26859#issuecomment-869144674).
- GitHub issue: [Explicitly fail (de)serialization of `java.time.*` types in absence of registered custom (de)serializers · Issue #2683 · FasterXML/jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2683).